# Solve using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits

I can’t understand how to solve this example using L’Hopital’s rule and why the answer is $1$.

$$\lim_{x\to0} \sin(x) ^{\tan(x)} $$

Comment: Use Latex and provide context and what you've tried. Otherwise question will be closed.

Comment: Let $y = \lim_\limits {x\to 0} \sin x^{\tan x}.$  Consider $\log y = \lim_\limits {x\to 0} \tan x \log \sin x$ and apply L'Hopital's to that.

Comment: Indeterminate form $0^0$.  How does your textbook do other $0^0$ problems?

Comment: It is not even defined unless you make it a right l8mit, $x\to0^+.$

Answer (score 2):

If you have some function raised to power that is another function itself, a good approach might be to go to exponent form:
$$f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp\{g(x)\ln f(x)\}$$
Using this idea:
$$\lim_{x\to0+}(\sin x)^{\tan x} = 
\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to0+} \frac{\ln\sin x}{\cot x}\right\}=$$
$$\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to0+} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot (-\sin^2 x)\right\}=\exp\{0\}=1$$